# Calculating CRC / Checksum of hex stream (sniffed)

Tags: hex, checksum, crc

I'm trying a few days to get the type of the CRC with the following hex stream (sniffed with wireshark):

The Hex data i sniffed:
0000001ec001075465737431323308557365726e616d650850617373776f7264d224

This should be the DATA in HEX:
0000001ec001075465737431323308557365726e616d650850617373776f7264

So the last 4 digits are the checksum, in this case d224

I used many code snippets (PHP, java), and some online checksum calcuation sites:
e.g.:
http://www.scadacore.com/field-applications/programming-calculators/online-checksum-calculator/

But I don't get the correct CRC value.

Thanks!

**Update 1**
Here are more hex streams with CRC included (the last 4 digits):

- 0000001dc001045465737409557365726e616d65310950617373776f726431cc96
- 0000001dc001045465737409557365726e616d65320950617373776f72643289d9
- 0000001dc001045465737409557365726e616d65330950617373776f726433b51c
- 0000001dc001045465737409557365726e616d65340950617373776f7264340347
- 0000001dc001045465737409557365726e616d65350950617373776f7264353f82

Comment: You would need more examples in order to reverse-engineer the CRC.

Comment: @MarkAdler I added more hex streams with crc included.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be the [ARC CRC](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/16.htm), polynomial `0x8005`, reflected, zero initial value and no final xor, if I discard the initial `0000001d` on each message, and take the CRC at the end to be put in the stream in little-endian order.

Comment: If I put my hex stream like the last one "0000001dc001045465737409557365726e616d65350950617373776f726435" on this site: http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html and choose CRC width CRC-16, Predefined: CRC16_ARC I got as result 0xFFB2, and not 0x3f82. Did I somehting wrong? - THX!

Comment: Yes, you didn't remove the initial `0000001d` like I said to.

Comment: You, you are the hero! Thank you very much!